# Cannot find -lgcc -s while Compiling C program with GCC

Tags: c, linux, gcc

I am trying to compile a C program with gcc using the below command

```
   gcc -r client.c -o exe
```

But getting these errors, and no generation of exe file:

```
 /usr/bin/ld cannot find -lgcc -s 
 collect2:  ld returned 1 exit status
```

Anyone tell me what I am missing and what is ld here?

Comment: Removed the `gdb` tag as that has nothing to do with this question.

Comment: @Mat i found my error its -g instead of -r.

Answer (score 3):

`ld` is the *linker* or *link editor*.  It is invoked by `gcc` to *link* the `.o` files produced by compiling your code together with various libraries (including `libgcc`) to produce an executable (`exe`).

Why are you passing `-r` to gcc?  Do you know what it does?  Don't do that.

Comment: i really don't know what -r does when it pass to gcc !!